# MooTools Class setOptions: Maximum call stack size exeeced

Tags: javascript, mootools, easeljs

I am trying to pass easelJS shape object as a parameter to the MooTools `new Class object` and then I get the `Maximum call stack size exceeded` error.

This works fine in my class code:

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.options = options;
}
```

But this causes an error:

```
initialize: function(options){
    this.setOptions(options);
}
```

What is wrong with this? setOptions usually works fine, but in this case it doesn't. Is there something wrong how `MooTools class->setOptions` handles input parameters?

In my example:

```
options = {"target": {easelShapeobject}}
```

Comment: Note that `options = {"target": {easelShapeobject}}` is invalid sintax. It should be `options = {"target": easelShapeobject}`. In case the error is a typo in the question, can you show the real code you are using?

Comment: My mistake. It was badly presented and my syntax was literally wrong. I meant that {easelShapeobject} is actually an object {} and the type of that object is easelShapeObject.

Comment: I solved this somehow, but I am not pleased with it. I moved one line "container.addChild(elem)" at to the end of my function and it worked fine. I believe that this is a ad hoc solution and the main issue lies  behind. I believe that MooTools setOptions-function causes this error. It can't handle complex objects.

Answer (score 0):

keep in mind that `setOptions` relies on `Object.merge` to copy props - but if the value is another object, it becomes recursive.

https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Core/Core.js#L385-L407

if you pass an easeljs instance (not sure on the API), it will be an object and it may try to follow that through and merge/clone until it finishes etc - it's not a good pattern to use as you'd end up with new objects that don't have the correct constructors.

Pass the easel stuff as an argument outside of the options.

```
new Class({
  implement: [Options],
  initialize: function(options, target){ 
    this.setOptions(options); 
    this.target = target || new createjs.Shape({..some default options}); 
  }
})
```

You retain the reference but don't break proto chain. if target is not defined, you can specify a default way to make one.

In the context of this, maybe element can be an `easeljs.Stage()` or an id of a canvas object to use etc.

tl;dr `setOptions` should not deal with non-primitive values. same issue would be seen via native `Object.assign` or `_.merge` / `_.clone` etc.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I finally did. I separated target from the options and I am passing it as an another parameter.